# Как печатать на таблицу из массива

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [fromto] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 1
    )

    [productname] => Array
    (
        [0] => Категория 17А
        [1] => Категория 5А
        [2] => Категория 6А
        [3] => Категория 1А
    )

    [position_price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13700
        [1] => 10200
        [2] => 5600
        [3] => 11690
    )
)
```

Мне нужно получить таблицу из этого массива:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Категория 17А</td>
            <td>13700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Категория 5А</td>
            <td>10200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Категория 6А</td>
            <td>5600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Категория 1А</td>
            <td>11690</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

`$array` - массив, который хранит все подмассивы.
Если мы точно уверены, что кол-во елементов вложеных массивов одинаковое, то:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($array['fromto'] as $k => $v): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $v ?></td>
            <td><?= $array['productname'][$k] ?></td>
            <td><?= $array['position_price'][$k] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, получилось.